# Display data for logged in user with same id from different table

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm self-learning, so pardon my ignorance.

I have 2 SQL tables: `user` and `product`, both tables contain `"user_id"` fields.

I have successfully created a login system that uses email and password fields from the first table (user).

I want to show specific information from the "product" table to the logged-in user. This information should be identified from the user_id field. (user with user_id of 1 should see the product with user_id of 1

login page has:

```
<?php

session_start();

$message = "";
require_once('account/pdoconnect.php');

    if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $message = '<label>All fields are required</label>';
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";
        $statement = $pdotestconn->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'password' => $_POST['password']
    )
        );
        $count = $statement->rowCount();
        if($count > 0) {
            $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
            header("location:account/index.php");
        }
        else {
            $message = '<label>Wrong Email or Password</label>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Index page has:

```
<?php session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]))
   {
    header("location:../login.php");
    exit;
   }
?>

<?php
 include("pdoconnect.php");

 $id = $_GET['user_id'];
 $result = $pdotestconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product inner join user on 
 user.user_id = product.user_id");
 $result->execute(array($id));
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Where I insert values with:

```
<?php
 echo $row['amount'];
?>
```

Problem:
I get the same value in the first row (with user_id = 2) for every user logged in

Comment: Probably you need to include WHERE clause in your second SQL statement `SELECT * FROM product inner join user on user.user_id = product.user_id WHERE user.user_id = :id`.

Comment: I would also suggest storing the user id in the session rather than fetching it from the request.  (BTW you don't need to join to the user table if the user_id is in the product  table).

Comment: @NigelRen can you help me with the code correction to store session in user_id

Comment: Don't store plaintext passwords in database. Use `password_hash()`!

Comment: I saw this: `'password' => $_POST['password']` and got the chills => please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it's probably best to store the user id in the session, so in your first source...

```
    if($count > 0) {
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];
        $_SESSION["userID"] = $row['ID'];  // Make sure ID is the column name from the user table
        header("location:account/index.php");
    }
```

then to display the data, fetch the user ID from the session...

```
 $id = $_SESSION["userID"];
 $result = $pdotestconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product
             WHERE product.user_id =:id");             
 $result->execute(['id'=> $id]);
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

BTW you don't need to join to the user table if the user_id is in the product table

Comment: there's an error on this line:

    
 $result->execute(['id' => $id]);

it says : parse error, expecting `')''

Comment: Try `$result->execute(array('id' => $id));` (Not sure what your error is though)

Comment: the rows come out empty, Note: the name of my column in user is user_id not ID and I modified your first code to:  $_SESSION["userID"] = $row['user_id'];

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump($row);` after the code above to check if the data is being retrieved.  Also there is nothing in your code which displays data, so not sure what code you are using.

Comment: False would indicate there isn't any data to fetch.  Check what `$id` has and make sure it is the users ID.

Comment: it's HTML, I'm getting frustrated here

Comment: it worked, I'm so sorry, I didn't add the second line in your first code: 
        $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any parameter on your query.

```
<?php
     include("pdoconnect.php");

     $id = $_GET['user_id'];
     $result = $pdotestconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product inner join user on 
     user.user_id = product.user_id WHERE product.user_id =:id");   
     $result ->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);          
     $result ->execute();
     $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get any output with this correction, all outputs are empty @metal